# Overalyed image not coming to bottom left in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using stack to overlay an image over another image.

Following is my code:

```
Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          //color: kBluePrimaryColor,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.23,
                          child: bannerimage == '' || bannerimage == null
                              ? Image.asset('images/user.jpg')
                              : Image.network(
                                  'image from api call'
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          child: Container(
                            //alignment: Alignment(0, -0.5),
                            width: 100,
                            height: 65,
                            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                shape: CircleBorder(), color: Colors.white),
                            child: DecoratedBox(
                              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      image: thumbnailimage == '' ||
                                              thumbnailimage == null
                                          ? AssetImage('images/user.jpg')
                                          : NetworkImage(
                                              'image called using api'
                                            ))),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
```

Using this code I am getting the following output:

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: instead of Align, use Positioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),   // this will give extra space below the image
              //color: kBluePrimaryColor,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.23,
              child: bannerimage == '' || bannerimage == null
                  ? Image.asset('images/user.jpg')
                  : Image.network(
                'image from api call'
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,     // how far you want image to be from bottom of the screen
              left: 10,     // how far you want image to be from left of the screen
              child: Container(
                //alignment: Alignment(0, -0.5),
                width: 100,
                height: 65,
                decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                    shape: CircleBorder(), color: Colors.white),
                child: DecoratedBox(
                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          image: thumbnailimage == '' ||
                              thumbnailimage == null
                              ? AssetImage('images/user.jpg')
                              : NetworkImage(
                              'image called using api'
                          ))),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: I tried this..the image does come down but it does not get below the background picture. I want the picture to move half down like I displayed in the second picture. Thanks

Comment: I have changed the code a bit. Add bottom padding to the container & set bottom of Positioned to 0.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
```

try using

```
Positioned(
       bottom:0 // or some value
       left:0 // or some value
```

Comment: I tried this..the image does come down but it does not get below the background picture. I want the picture to move half down like I displayed in the second picture. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to align a widget inside a Stack widget, parent the desired widget with Positioned widget, like this:

```
Stack(
   children:[
      Positioned(
      top: 10,//sample position from top,
      bottom: 20,//sample position from bottom
      right: 30 //sample position from right,
      left:40 //sample postition from left,
      child: Container(
                //alignment: Alignment(0, -0.5),
                width: 100,
                height: 65,
                decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                  shape: CircleBorder(), color: Colors.white),
                  child: DecoratedBox(
                    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                       fit: BoxFit.cover,
                       image: thumbnailimage == '' ||
                         thumbnailimage == null
                         ? AssetImage('images/user.jpg')
                         : NetworkImage(
                            'image called using api'
              ))),
           ),
         ),
      )
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I just edit your code, please change the images. Here is the code.

```
String bannerimage;
String thumbnailimage;

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _testState createState() => _testState();
}

class _testState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final orientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          height: 400,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 350,
                //color: kBluePrimaryColor,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                //height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.23,
                child: bannerimage == '' || bannerimage == null
                    ? Image.network(
                        'https://www.charlotteobserver.com/latest-news/wikp4c/picture248009850/alternates/FREE_1140/imgmaxpreps.jpg')
                    : Image.network(
                        'https://www.charlotteobserver.com/latest-news/wikp4c/picture248009850/alternates/FREE_1140/imgmaxpreps.jpg',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(150.0)),
                  width: 140,
                  height: 140,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      child: bannerimage == '' || bannerimage == null
                          ? ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                              child: Image.network(
                                'https://www.charlotteobserver.com/latest-news/wikp4c/picture248009850/alternates/FREE_1140/imgmaxpreps.jpg',
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            )
                          : ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                              child: Image.network(
                                'https://www.charlotteobserver.com/latest-news/wikp4c/picture248009850/alternates/FREE_1140/imgmaxpreps.jpg',
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```